# German in the US importing his reliable car to Europe

Tags: usa, germany, eu, regulations

I'm German living in Massachusetts, USA. I plan to stay here for 4 more years for work.

I just bought a reliable new car Toyota Corolla LE 2023. I am a defensive driver who would do maybe 15k miles a year max. After 4 years, I don't want to sell my car here e.g. $8000 lower for depreciation and get another new car in the EU. I would much rather pay e.g. $2000 for shipping with some stuff in the seat/trunk and I can wait for up to 3 months for my car to arrive (container sharing or any inexpensive & reliable shipping option). By that time I would have completed the customs-free category to import my own car from the US to Germany/EU by having lived in the US for at least 1 year and having owned a car for at least 6 months.

The only thing apart from shipping is to make sure my Corolla conforms to EU standards. As it's a 2023 model, it comes with Amber style indicators/blinkers/turn signals and the emission standards should be up to the EU regulation.

Am I missing something obvious or do I need to consider anything?

Although the US is fun, I look forward to going back home in 4 years with my reliable car and being done with moving for good. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Contacting a specialised auto importer over in Germany that knows about German regulations is **very likely** your best bet

Comment: Useful link: https://www.adac.de/rund-ums-fahrzeug/auto-kaufen-verkaufen/import-export/import-usa-kanada/ . The tricky part will be to figure out if the US model complies with EU regulations.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll ask Toyota (Manufacturer) if the US 2023 version conforms to EU standards as well.

Comment: In 4 years regulations can change a lot. I don’t think anybody can vouch for what they will be at that point.

Comment: Perhaps the speedometer/odometer may have to show km/h and km?

Comment: Checking if the same car (and the listed technical data shown) is being sold in Germany is one way to see if there are any major standard differences. [Test Toyota Corolla Hybrid 2023; Verbrauch, Daten, Preis](https://www.adac.de/rund-ums-fahrzeug/autokatalog/marken-modelle/toyota/toyota-corolla/)

Comment: Make sure your "Tacho" shows both kilometers *and* miles per hour. Not sure if that is a legal requirement, but constantly making rough guesses is a pain you can certainly do without.

Comment: A basic summery of what is required from Dezember 1998: [Importfahrzeug-Richtlinie | TÜV SÜD](https://www.tuvsud.com/de-de/branchen/mobilitaet-und-automotive/import-und-zulassung/importfahrzeug-richtlinie). Tachometer must be changed. Odometer change is not required.

Comment: The tachometer has both mph and km/h. Need to install rear fog lights and turn-signal-display on mirrors (left & right) or on front doors (left & right). Good idea to compare the specs of the same model in DE & USA.

Comment: To avoid language confusion: "Speedometer" shows vehicle velocity (mph and/or km/h). "Tachometer" shows engine rotation speed (RPM).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, § 57 StVZO says speedometer and odometer have to show kilometers.

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Yes, but the TÜV document says that for imported cars, for the odometer (Wegstreckenzähler), an exemption can be applied for.